# Using ajax with nodeJs

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I cant find a solution to pass the result data to database. What nodeJS library should I use or what way should I use to make this work? Thanks in advance for your help.

```html
<form action="/scheda-ascolti/save" method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="schedaAscolti">
    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipologia-attivita" class="col-sm-3">Tipologia Attivita' di Controllo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select id="tipologia" name="tipologiaControllo" class="form-control" required>
                        <option disabled selected value style="display: none"></option>
                        <option value="ascolto">Ascolto</option>
                        <option value="misteryCall">Mistery Call</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3">Operatore Telefonico Valutato</label>

                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" name="operatore" class="form-control" id="codiceOperatore" value="TS" minlength="5" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apertura-chiamata" class="col-sm-3">Apertura </br> Chiamata</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="aperturaChiamata" class="apertura-chiamata"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="identificazione-problema" class="col-sm-3">Identificazione del problema</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="identificazioneProblema" class="identificazione-problema"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="formula-soluzione" class="col-sm-3">Individuazione e Formulazione</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="formulaSoluzione" class="formula-soluzione"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="riepilogo-chiamata" class="col-sm-3">Riepilogo, conferma e chiusura della chiamata</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="riepilogoChiamata" class="riepilogo-chiamata"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="caratteristiche" class="col-sm-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Linguaggio, empatia, ascolto, impegno, TMC">Caratteristiche e </br> Capacita'</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="caratteristicheCapacita'" class="caratteristiche"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="propone-csi" class="col-sm-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="1=SI; 0=NO">Propone </br> CSI</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="hidden" name="proponeCSI" class="propone-csi"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apertura-ticket" class="col-sm-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Se necessario (1=SI; 0=NO)">Apertura </br> Ticket</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select onchange="count();" name="aperturaTicket" class="form-control non-neccesario" required>
                        <!--<option disabled selected value style="display: none"></option>-->
                        <option value="0">Non Neccesario</option>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="aggiornamento-ticket" class="col-sm-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="1=SI; 0=NO">Aggiornamento Ticket di Chiamata</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select onchange="count();" name="aggiornamentoTicket" class="form-control aggiornamento-ticket" required>
                        <!--<option disabled selected value style="display: none"></option>-->
                        <option value="0">No DataMax</option>
                        <option value="0">0</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="critica-comportamentale"class="col-sm-3">Criticità </br> comportamentale</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select name="criticaComportamentale" class="form-control critica-comportamentale" required>
                        <option disabled selected value style="display: none"></option>
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                        <option value="1">Si</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="note-commenti" class="col-sm-3">Note e </br> Commenti</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <textarea name="noteCommenti" class="note-commenti"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inviata-segnalazione" class="col-sm-3" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="es. email, skype, ...">Inviata </br> Segnalazione</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select name="inviataSegnalazione" class="form-control" required>
                        <option disabled selected value style="display: none"></option>
                        <option value="0">No</option>
                        <option value="1">Si</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group boxed-rating">
                <label for="valutazione-finale" class="col-sm-12 valutazione-testo" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="da 0 a 100">Valutazione Finale</label>
                <div id="result" class="box-rating valutazione-finale"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Salva</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer -->
</form>
```

```js
var data = {            
    'aperturaChiamata': parseInt($('input[name=aperturaChiamata]').val()),
    'identificazioneProblema': parseInt($('input[name=aperturaChiamata]').val()),                
    'riepilogoChiamata': parseInt($('input[name=riepilogoChiamata]').val()),                
    'caratteristiche': parseInt($('input[name=caratteristiche]').val()),                
    'formulaSoluzione': parseInt($('input[name=formulaSoluzione]').val()),        
    'proponeCsi': parseInt($('input[name=proponeCsi]').val()),                
    'aperturaTicket': parseInt($('input[name=aperturaTicket]').val()),                
    'aggiornamentoTicket': parseInt($('input[name=aggiornamentoTicket]').val()),                
    'valutazioneFinale': $('#result').text(result)
};

$("schedaAscolti").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        require: {
            type: "POST",
            url: "/scheda-ascolti/save",
            data: data
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Server Side

```
router.post('/scheda-ascolti/save', function (req, res, next) {
    var tipologiaControllo = req.body.tipologiaControllo;
    var operatore = req.body.operatore;
    var aperturaChiamata = req.body.aperturaChiamata;
    var identificazioneProblema = req.body.identificazioneProblema;
    var formulaSoluzione = req.body.formulaSoluzione;
    var riepilogoChiamata = req.body.riepilogoChiamata;
    var caratteristicheCapacita = req.body.caratteristicheCapacita;
    var proponeCSI = req.body.proponeCSI;
    var aperturaTicket = req.body.aperturaTicket;
    var aggiornamentoTicket = req.body.aggiornamentoTicket;
    var criticaComportamentale = req.body.criticaComportamentale;
    var noteCommenti = req.body.noteCommenti;
    var inviataSegnalazione = req.body.inviataSegnalazione;

    res.redirect('/scheda-ascolti');
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: Not a good idea to set this in the data object: `'valutazioneFinale' : $('#result').text(result)`.

Comment: So how can i do this @Rory

Comment: @ArditKurti not sure why you're asking me, I have no experience of Node.

Comment: @Rory i thought u knew something as u answered thanks anyway mate

Comment: Nope, I only fixed the formatting of your question.

Comment: Shouldn't `$("schedaAscolti")` be `$("#schedaAscolti")` also to prevent the default submit you should `return false` in after your ajax call.

Comment: Thnx anyway i managed to solve it on my own @alex

Answer (score 0):

'/scheda-ascolti' endpoint GET or POST ?